# Do the Kollidorians of "One-Way Journey" possess psychic powers?

Tags: aliens, psychic, robert-silverberg

Do the Kollidorians of Silverberg's "[One-Way Journey](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58624)" possess psychic powers?

Looking at [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/208913/42059) translated summary of "One-Way Journey", it says that of a Kollidorian woman, "Thetona" and her first interaction with Falk:

> Thetona psychically replaced the absent mother.

Is that translation accurate, which would imply that by "psychically", it means psychic powers?

Comment: I don't believe "psychically" in your quotation implies "psychic powers". Have you read the story? You can read it here: https://archive.org/details/Infinity_v03n01_1957-11_Gorgon776/page/n45/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: The OED defines "psychically" as "in a psychic or psychical manner; with reference to the soul or mind; mentally, psychologically." Nothing about fortune-telling or other occult powers.

Comment: @user14111 - Thanks for the story link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no evidence the Kollidorians have any psychic powers, and none are required to explain the story.

The crewman, Matt Falk, has suffered a recurrence of a birth trauma, and thereafter became psychologically dependent on the alien woman as a mother-substitute when she offered him sympathy for his pain.

The story is largely a psychological study, with the captain and psych officer trying to keep Falk from deserting.  I expect that "psychically" is a mistranslation of "psychologically."

Comment: How is it a mistranslation? Did you see my comment quoting the definition of "psychically"  from the online OED, which offers "psychologically" as a synonym? "Psychically" is a real word, not an invention of the Psychic Friends Network.

Comment: @user14111 I did not see your comment; I had my answer open for a while as I decided I wanted to refresh my memory of the story.  As to the OED, there are a lot of words - *especially* in SF - whose commonly understood meaning diverges from the official dictionary meaning.  This is Campbell-era SF; "psychic" has certain freighting.

Comment: Thanks for answering! In your edit to my question, is there a reason to link to isfdb instead of the archive.org version of the story?

Comment: @Malady I've had experience with stuff posted on archive.org disappearing.  For example, there aren't currently any issues of *Star Detective/Uncanny Tales*, and in the past both *Galaxy* and *Super Science Stories* have been taken down.  (And when they come back, the URLs aren't necessarily the same.)  At least with the ISFDb link, people can search for any of the various appearances.  That's no reason _not_ to put a link to archive.org, just that if I'm only going to put in 1 link it'll be to ISFDb.